# how to query objects lookup relationship and count records?

Tags: soql

I have an custom Invoice object with a look-up relationship to Accounts.

I'm trying to query the data base to get the total number of invoices of the accounts where `Connection_Date__c` has a value (`Connection_Date__c` is a custom field of Accounts object)

How can I do this? The query I'm using gives me only the number of accounts but not the number of invoices.

`SELECT Name,(SELECT name FROM Invoices__r) FROM Account WHERE Connection_Date__c != null`

Answer (score 1):

In SOQL, it's almost easier to write queries that are driven from the child rather than the parent. This is opposite of SQL

Try a query that matches this pattern:

SELECT Count() FROM ChildTable WHERE ChildTable.parentField != Null

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT (Parent_Api_Name_In_Child_Object),
    COUNT(ID)
        (Child_Realtionship_Name__r.Parent_Fields....)
        FROM (Child_Object_Api_Name)
        GROUP BY (Parent_Api_Name_Child_Object,
                        Parent Feilds with API Names)
        HAVING COUNT(ID){>,<,=,{Optional}}
```

it is an SQL queried answer 
Let me know in case of any questions